# Tkinter: Checkbuttons and list

Tags: python-3.x, checkbox, tkinter

Hey Guys I have a problem with checkboxen in tkinter. Can someone say where my fault is ?

```
def edit_contact_gui(self):
    """GUI to edit the created contacts."""
    self.edit_contact_wd = tk.Tk()
    self.edit_contact_wd.title('Edit Contacts of the Phonebook:"%s"'\
                               % self.book)
    self.button_edit = tk.Button(self.edit_contact_wd, text = 'Edit',\
                                 command = self.edit_contact)


    try:
        with open('%s.txt' % self.book, 'rb') as file:
            book = pickle.load(file)
            x = 1
            self.var_lst = []
            for i in book:
                var = tk.IntVar()
                tk.Label(self.edit_contact_wd, text = i).grid(row = x, \
                                                                column = 0)

                tk.Checkbutton(self.edit_contact_wd, text = 'edit', \
                               variable = var).grid(row = x, column = 1)
                self.var_lst.append(var.get())

                x += 1

            self.button_edit.grid(row = x+1, column = 1)

    except FileNotFoundError:
        tk.Label(self.edit_contact_wd, text = 'The phonebook has no entrys!', fg = 'red').grid(row = 1, column = 0)

    self.edit_contact_wd.mainloop()

def edit_contact(self):
    print(self.var_lst)
```

My GUI output works, but the programm return me a List [0,0,0,0,0] full of zeros. In my opinion the Checkbox who is marked has return a 1 but it doesnt to it. Why? Can you help me ?

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Do you already have a GUI running by the time `edit_contact_gui` is called, or is this the first time that you create an instance of `Tk`?

Comment: I have already an GUI. The to function are only under function (Pop-Up Windows.)

Comment: If that's the case, part of your problem is that you should _not_ be creating a second instance of `Tk`, and should not be calling `mainloop` inside this function.

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep `IntVar` (`var`) on list, not value from `IntVar` (`var.get()`)

```
 self.var_lst.append(var) # without .get()
```

and in `edit_contact()` you have to use `get()`

```
for var in self.var_lst:
    print(var.get())
```

Comment: But if i do this i have only zeros and not 1 if the checkbox is marked

Comment: you should have `1` when you check checkbuttons and click `Edit` button. Maybe you have different problem or program shows you some error message when you run it in console/terminal/cmd.exe/powershell. I can't check it and I don't see any problem in this part of code.

Comment: btw: as said @BryanOakley - if you have two `Tk()` or two `mainloop()` then `tkinter` may work incorrectly.

Comment: It is because i have more Tk() but how can i fix it?

Comment: You have to use `Toplevel()` to create second/third window. And remove second `mainloop()`